# What is getting merged?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following method:

```
increaseCount() {
  console.log(this);

  this.setState(prevState => ({       // X
    count: prevState.count + 1
  }));

  this.setState(function(prevState) {      // Y
    return { count: prevState.count + 1 };
  });

  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }, function() {   // Z
    return this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  });
}
```

X and Y will increment the counter by two when used together.
Z will increment the counter by 2 when used alone

Why doesn't the counter increment by 4 when X,Y, and Z are used?  Also, if I place block Z above X and Y it works as expected and increments by 4.  Could someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of setState as an async call. When you use `this.setState((prevState) => {})` you pass it a function that will update the state based on its previous value. On the other hand when you use it like `this.setState({count:this.state.count+1})` you are passing an actual value to the object.

That said, setState actions will update the state in the order they are called but they will not wait for the previous call to finish when they are actually called. So in your case X and Y will update the state based on the previous value (so 0 -> 1, then 1->2) however Z is already called with a value of `{count: this.sate.count + 1}` which might be `{count: 0 + 1}` at the time it is called. The second parameter in Z is a callback that is called once the first update is finished. This way `this.state.count` will be 1 already when it is called, resulting 2 again.

If you place Z on the top, it will increment `count` to 2 as stated above, then the next two setState calls will increase it based on the actual `prevState` at the time they are called.

Illustration:

```
In the js code:
InitialState: count = 0;
X called -> (count: prevState + 1);
Y called -> (count: prevState + 1);
Z called -> (count: 0 + 1); 

Meanwhile asynchronously:
InitialState: count = 0
X -> prevState=0, count = 0 + 1;
Y -> prevState=1, count = 1 + 1;
Z -> count = 1; then called again for (count: this.state.count + 1) which is now (count: 1 + 1)
```

Comment: thank you. This almost makes sense (to me).  But if setState is async how do we know the Y block will wait for the X block to finish?

Comment: The calls themselfs don't wait, so Y will be called before X finished. However react assures that the state updates will happen in the order defined by the calls (asynchronously). Since not a value but a function is passed `prevState` will be the value when the actual state update happens not when `setState` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Because setState is async. Let's say you have initial count 0 when you have all three of them running line by line. The `this.state.count` value block Z gets is actually 0 instead of 2.

Comment: then why isn't `this.state.count` value block Y gets not 0?